# Paging ObjectDataSource

Tags: asp.net, paging, objectdatasource

My ASP page code:

```
  <asp:ObjectDataSource runat="server" ID="odsResults" OnSelecting="odsResults_Selecting" />
    <tr><td>
    <wssawc:SPGridViewPager ID="sgvpPagerTop" runat="server" GridViewId="sgvConversionResults" />
    </td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" class="ms-vb">
            <wssawc:SPGridView 
                runat="server" 
                ID="sgvConversionResults" 
                AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                RowStyle-CssClass=""
                AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="ms-alternating" 
                />
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Class code:

```
public partial class Convert : System.Web.UI.Page

{
   ...
   private  DataTable resultDataSource = new DataTable();
   ...

  protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ...

        resultDataSource.Columns.Add("Column1");
        resultDataSource.Columns.Add("Column2");
        resultDataSource.Columns.Add("Column3");
        resultDataSource.Columns.Add("Column4");
        ...
        odsResults.TypeName = GetType().AssemblyQualifiedName;
        odsResults.SelectMethod = "SelectData";
        odsResults.SelectCountMethod = "GetRecordCount";
        odsResults.EnablePaging = true;
        sgvConversionResults.DataSourceID = odsResults.ID;
        ConversionResultsCreateColumns();
        sgvConversionResults.AllowPaging = true;
        ...
    }

    protected void btnBTN_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // add rows into resultDataSource
    }

    public DataTable SelectData(DataTable ds,int startRowIndex,int maximumRows)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        dt.Columns.Add("Column1");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column2");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column3");
        dt.Columns.Add("Column4");

        for (int i =startRowIndex; i<startRowIndex+10 ;i++)
        {   
            if (i<ds.Rows.Count)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(ds.Rows[i][0].ToString(), ds.Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                ds.Rows[i][2].ToString(), ds.Rows[i][3].ToString());
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }

    public int GetRecordCount(DataTable ds)
    {
        return ds.Rows.Count;
    }

    protected void odsResults_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
    {
        e.InputParameters["ds"] = resultDataSource;

    }

}
```

On clicking the button `resultDataSource` receives some rows. Page reload and we can see result in `sgvConversionResults`. First 10 rows. But after click next page in pager we have message "There are no items to show in this view". When I try debug I find that after `postBack` page (on click next page) input params "ds" is blank, `ds.Rows.Count = 0`  and etc... As though `resultDataSource` became empty((
What did I do incorrectly?

---

onPostBack all variables get default values, sgvConversionResults save her structure but has clear rows. How I can save sgvConversionResults data onPostBack event???

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sgvConversionResults.DataBind();
}
```

Your code seems a bit convoluted though, any particular reason you are using an ObjectDataSource? Cause you can bind the datatable directly to the gridview in the codebehind

Answer (score 1):

I transmit resultDataSource with ViewState and this work success!